# Characters change in javascript file after uploading it to S3 bucket

Tags: javascript, d3.js, amazon-s3

I have d3 as a dependency in my repository. After uploading it to the S3 bucket, web page throws an illegal token error pointing to the d3.js file. First I build it through the Codeship pipeline, then I tried to manually upload the d3.js file; the same thing happens.

```
d3.js:1261 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

line 1261:

```
var Îµ = 1e-6, Îµ2 = Îµ * Îµ, Ï€ = Math.PI, Ï„ = 2 * Ï€, Ï„Îµ = Ï„ - Îµ, halfÏ€ = Ï€ / 2, d3_radians = Ï€ / 180, d3_degrees = 180 / Ï€;
```

but the file looks like this in my IDE (web storm)

```
 var ε = 1e-6, ε2 = ε * ε, π = Math.PI, τ = 2 * π, τε = τ - ε, halfπ = π / 2, d3_radians = π / 180, d3_degrees = 180 / π;
```

Why is this happening and how am I going to avoid it ?

edit: I wanted to add how i inject the dependency in case it gives any idea to anyone:

index.html:

```
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="/bower_components/d3/d3.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

Dependencies are injected to HTML with a gulp task :

```
...
// Bower assets
    var bower = gulp.src(bowerFiles(), {read: false});

    return target
        .pipe(inject(bower, {
            transform: typeTransform,
            name: 'bower'
        }))
....
```

bower.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "d3": "3.5.17",
...
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem with adding charset attribute to the dependency:     `<script src="/bower_components/d3/d3.js" type="application/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>`
For more information I recommend to read the specs here: https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/links.html#adef-charset

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Dreamweaver check the option: Include Unicode Signature (BOM), before save the file:

[image]

Or look for similar option on your editor.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am not using Dreamweaver. Do you know the underlying issue here? Why is this happening?